# MAC | Xamarin Studio | UiTest | File -> New and Build menu options are grayed out after opening existing project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-studio

Whenever I open an existing UiTest project in Xamarin Studio almost all of the menu options become grayed out (not clickable).  And the only way to fix it, is to uninstall and reinstall Xamarin.

If I only create New projects, this problem doesnt happen.  Has anyone experienced this?  What can i do?

[image: Unable to click File->New-> Solution]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe, that existing project was out-of-date and is not using the same format as your new Xamarin Studio. It could be that someone create that project along time ago, and you recently update your Xamarin Studio. Therefore, the format of that existing project is not quite compatible with the new Xamarin Studio.

---

I have seen some similar issues. For example, when I open my existing game project in Xamarin Studio Community, and select the button "Project" on the top menu bar, I can see that the button "Project Options" is gray out. I ask people at Xamarin and no one can explain why.